# How to write a custom UDP NPL parser for Microsoft Network Monitor

Tags: network-programming, udp, network-monitoring

I am trying to figure out how to write a custom UDP NPL parser for Microsoft Network Monitor.

My packets are in the simple form of <int_sequence_id>|<QR|WRITE|READ>|<string_data>.

Has anyone figured it out how to build on top of UDP parser a custom parser?